# Counting function

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone please explain how the answer was obtained. Let $S = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $T = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. How many functions are there from $S$ into $T$. The answer is $2401$.
I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f:S \to T$ is completely specified by the values $f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)$.

Each of these values can be any of the 7 elements of $T$.

Hence there are $7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 = 7^4 = 2401$ possible functions.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you factored $2401=7^4?$  That is a big clue.  You have $7$ choices for $f(a)$, then $7$ choices for $f(b)$ and ....  As the choices are independent, you multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the four elements of $S$ should be mapped to one of the seven elements of $T$. There is no reason why more than one element of $S$ can't map to the same element of $T$. Hence the total number of ways of doing this is $7^4=2401$.